# Maximum load of my application or server

Tags: cluster-computing, load-testing

How to know the maximum load of my application or server.
I need to know this to decide whether my application need to be cluster or not.

If we have to do a test to know, so we need a lot of concurrent client to hit the server. But we can't simulate this like in the real world, how to simulate concurrent millions of people..?

Maybe we can test for a single server in a production. But when it fail, it will be a bad user experience. Of course we can improve it after that.

Knowing the maximum load earlier might be better.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a load testing framework like [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) (very good) or [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) (limited but easy). Both written in Java, but can load test any web application.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't familiar with JMeter or other open source installed tools, try a web or cloud-based tool. I'm going to recommend trying [Loadzen](http://loadzen.com) (full disclosure, I run this site) that would let you record a user scenario and simulate distributed load and only charges on a per-test basis.

No matter which cloud-based tool you chose to use though, I'd recommend making sure you start small and ramp up slowly, otherwise you run the risk of not finding the tipping point for your application server.